# Plotting each year as separate series using ggplot2 and faceting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data for nine rivers from 2001 to 2009. I want to create the graph of nine facets and each facets I want to have nine lines for each year. The x-axis would be from Jan to December. So far I have come up to this:

The code I used is as follows:

```
testseries<- read.csv("testseries.csv")
meltedtestseries <- melt(testseries,id=c("date"))
head(meltedtestseries)
ggplot(meltedtestseries,aes(x=date,y=value))+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free")+xlab("Date")+ylab("Discharge(cms)")
```

The graph I obtained is as follows:
[image]

Now, I want to change the X axis in Months and plot nine curves for each year for each facet. I know I need to change color=year or something like that. But it didn't work out. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

The dataset can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykhu8vc9211xtzu/testseries.csv

Jdbaba

**Edit: Extra information**

I also tried this code:

```
ggplot(meltedtestseries,aes(x=as.Date(date),y=value,color=date))+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free")+xlab("Date")+ylab("Discharge(cms)")
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If you've already faceted by river, how will you get nine curves in each facet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're missing is a grouping by `year`. Assuming your `data.frame` is `df`,

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df1 <- read.csv("~/Downloads/testseries.csv")
df <- melt(df1,id=c("date"))
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

# get `year` first
# df$year <- as.POSIXlt(df$date)$year + 1900 (old code)
# df$year <- format(df$date,'%Y') # following @agstudy's comment.
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=date, y=value))
# group/colour by year
p <- p + geom_line(aes(colour=factor(year))) 
p <- p + scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set3") 
p <- p + facet_wrap(~ variable, scales="free", ncol=3)
p <- p + xlab("Date") + ylab("Discharge(cms)")
p
```

This gives:

[image: ggplot2_facet]

**Edit 2:** If this is not what you're looking for, then maybe you require facetting with 2 variables with `facet_grid` as follows:

```
df$year <- factor(as.POSIXlt(df$date)$year + 1900)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=date, y=value))
p <- p + geom_line() 
p <- p + facet_grid(variable ~ year)
p <- p + xlab("Date") + ylab("Discharge(cms)")
p
```

Gives a dense graph:

[image: ggplot2_facet_grid_dense]

Comment: Arun, Thank you so much for your reply. I want to plot the continuous data for each year for each rivers. Right now I was able to plot the data for each rivers on different facets. Now, I want to work under each facets. For each facet I want to have 9 series. Let's say for river "1" I want to plot as one year. Probably I may need to use number from 1-365 or something for each year and then plot the graph so that all the series will overlap.

Comment: @ Arun, Thank you so much for your time and effort. The first solution looks good and is very close to what I need. I don't think what I need is possible. I really appreciate your help. I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: +1 nice dashboard! 1900 looks a little bit hard coded..maight I suggest something like `df$year <- format(df$date,'%Y')` to get year..